# Configure Client Authentication with Digital Certificates on Apache HTTP Server

Tags: http, authentication, ssl

Updating the topic on an authentication, I progressed in the execution of the client authentication through SSL. Look at the following image:

[See the SSL Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gem5v.png)

The .p12 extension of the client certificate was installed and installed on the computer.

But two problems remain:

1) Does not ask the password of the certificate to authenticate;

2) The error still appears and does not display the page: `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`.

Can someone help me?

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/empresa
    ServerName empresa

    # enable ssl
    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ssl/ca.empresa.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/ca.empresa.key

    # this location requires client cert 
    <Location /webservice>
        SSLRequireSSL
        SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Empresa LDA." 
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth  1
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: http://edoceo.com/howto/apache-authentication-ssl

Comment: Please show the error traces, the exact configuration of your server, and the piece of code you are using if you expect someone could help you

Comment: I already put it as information you requested, Thanks

Comment: What certificate have you installed in chrome? You need one issued by MyCA.crt

Comment: I already installed certificate client. But not work, the same error.

Comment: is HTTPS connection without client authentication working properly? Is chrome prompting the certificate selection ? You could  review apache logs to see what is happening. Try also to change `require` to `optional_no_ca` and see what happens

Comment: I tried to change `require` to `optional_no_ca` and the same error.